# I can't print my array outside the " for loop"

Tags: c

I try to print the array but it doesn't work I get a different output than the numbers entered by the user.
PS: I need to print it outside the for loop.
extra question: How to reset the numbers entered by the user? (code)

```
#define LENGTH 10
int main (){
    int measurements[LENGTH];
    int x;

    for(x=0; x<LENGTH; x++){
    printf("Enter number #%d: ", x+1);
    scanf("%d", &measurements[x]);

    if(measurements[x]==0){
        break;
    }


    }
        printf(" %d ", measurements[x]);//won't work
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf() returns a value - you should check it.

Comment: @MartinJames what do you mean?

Comment: What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: Well, your code did work. But what do you mean by you want to print in outside the for loop? If you want to print it outside the for loop you need to again use another for loop to print the contents.

Comment: I didn't see what's wrong when running your code, but it seems it does not match your expectations.

Comment: If !X you exit the loop. After zero your program terminates

Comment: @Zuzu you should read the man page for `scanf`, it might save you asking another 50 questions about this complicated function.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of inputs and their unexpected outputs? If so, please add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print the array:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
    printf("%d\n", measurements[i]);
}
```

Code:

```
#define LENGTH 10
int main (){
    int measurements[LENGTH];
    int x, i;

    for(x=0; x<LENGTH; x++){
        printf("Enter number #%d: ", x+1);
        scanf("%d", &measurements[x]);

        if(measurements[x]==0){
            break;
        }
    }


    /*
    *this for loop will print the array 
    *till the index where 0 is entered. 
    *it will not print 0
    */

    printf("\nHere are your measurements:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        printf("%d\n", measurements[i]);
    }

    /*reset part*/
    for(i = 0; i < LENGHT; i++){
        measurements[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you could also use [memset](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) from string.h instead of reset part.

```
measurements = memset(measurements, 0, 10);
```

**Also keep in mind:** there is no such thing as empty array/ reseted array in c, it only depends on what what you define to be empty/reset value of array elements. even if you dont set the 0 in array its still empty by another **perspective**.

Comment: YES! thank you so much

Comment: accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 5
int measurements[LENGTH];
int x,y,i;
void abc();
int main (){
abc();
printf("1 to reset,0 to not");
scanf("%d",&y);
if(y == 1){
abc();
}
else{
    printf("BYE!");
}
}
void abc(){
for(x = 0; x < LENGTH; x++){
printf("Enter number #%d: ", x + 1);
scanf("%d", &measurements[x]);
}
for(i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
printf("\n%d\n ", measurements[i]);
}
}
```

This will reset the numbers entered by the user and gonna print the elements of array.

Comment: You should not suggest to call `main` recursively. It is not a good idea to do so in the most cases.

Comment: Please suggest a new way to do this besides using main () . @mch

Comment: If you want to do something repeatedly, you can use a `while` loop: https://ideone.com/V5QmNR

Comment: i made that thing in a function this time and called the function. Is it still the same thing? @mch